# iOS: Is there a standard way to check if the user interacts with OTHER UI elements than the given one?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

This seems like something just about every iOS app would require, yet I can't find any relevant info on it, possibly due to how hard it is to phrase this question coherently.

Specifically, I need to **perform a certain action** (hide a couple of buttons) whenever the user **interacts with anything else in the app's interface other than a given element** (the aforementioned buttons).

**For an example:** think of the way the Apple-provided swipe action buttons work, i.e. when you swipe from right to left in a table cell, the buttons slide out, but then if you try to tap/drag/do anything else outside of the action buttons, they slide away again and the interface doesn't respond to whatever action you were trying to perform, thus making sure the buttons are never left hanging out when the user is doing something else in the app.

**So my question:** is there a standard way of doing this, like some delegate function that automatically catches any user interactions with the UI except for a specific element?

Or do I have to write code to check whether the user taps/drags/etc. on every single other UI element on the screen at the time?

Comment: You could probably use a custom gesture recognizer on the window, or just override `UIWindow.sendEvent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> think of the way the Apple-provided swipe action buttons work, i.e. when you swipe from right to left in a table cell, the buttons slide out, but then if you try to tap/drag/do anything else outside of the action buttons, they slide away again and the interface doesn't respond to whatever action you were trying to perform, thus making sure the buttons are never left hanging out when the user is doing something else in the app. So my question: is there a standard way of doing this

Override the main view's `func hitTest(CGPoint, with: UIEvent?)`. All touches pass through here, telling you what subview was touched.

So normally, you'll just return the result of calling `super`. But when you are in this special mode, you'll actually look to see what `super` returns to you. If it is your interactive subview, return it, so that the user can interact with it in the normal way. Otherwise, don't return it (return `nil`) and do whatever else you want to do (e.g. leave the special mode and restore the interface).